# How do I get a value from Datatable after Select Method in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get value from Datatable after Select Method.
Select Method should return only one record.

```
 Dim y As DataTable = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("tb"), DataTable)
 Dim products = y.[Select]("StnID" = "'" + stnID + "'")
 Dim size = DirectCast(Products(0)("Shape"), String)
```

if I replace products with y--(DirectCast(y.Rows(0)("Shape"), String), it works.(which is before Select method, so it's useless)

products is datarow object and I can't seem to get the value same way as datatable.
How do I get value from datarows?

Comment: DataTable.Select method return array of DataRow.

Answer (score 0):

The select Method of the datatable object returns a collection of rows so you have to iterate throw the rows to get desired value;